# Auto quote reserved words with Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is there a way to auto quote reserved words with Doctrine 2 when using `$entityManager->find('entity', id)` ?

When using the query builder this can be done but there should be a global configuration setting that does this? I don't want to have to specify it in the annotations for the reserved words.

Answer (score 103):

This was an issue I raised a while back with the Doctrine team.

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2409

The ticket was closed with the comment:

> You have to manually escape characters with @Column(name="`integer`")

So I guess you'd need to deal with any reserved keywords in your annotations

Comment: I just found out that the doctrine DBAL is now shipped with the cli tool \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\ReservedWordsCommand() which is really useful for scanning your Entities for anything that might cause an issue. Try running "doctrine dbal:reserved-words" to test it out.

Comment: IMHO doctrine is broken here. Anywhere else where the system doesn't escape things for you it would be called an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: 2 years alter, still the same issue: you can create a table with a column named "primary" but then you won't be able to use this table. It doesn't look normal to me that a DBAL let such basic task to the user.

Comment: Not escaping column names is kind of ghetto in my opinion.  I've used several ORMs over the years and this problem has only come up in Doctrine.  I hit this problem because I had a column named 'group'.

Comment: This issue is pretty silly.  I can't use the table name "release" because of a reserved keyword.  Haven't found a way around this even with a "`". I don't like plural table names, but because of this issue and until I find a work around, I have one plural table name.  Driving my OCD crazy.

Comment: Can't believe this issue was closed as invalid o.O

Comment: There is a Doctrine DBAL issue about this here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-40

Comment: Seems that the solution don't works if you JOIN tables with this field. I can't believe it!

Comment: Look at this entry in the documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#identifier-quoting-and-legacy-databases

Comment: This works until you need to write a DQL query that retrieves fields with reserved names. Doctrine converts `SELECT d.integer ...` to `SELECT d.\`integer\` AS \`integer\`0 ...` which is of course, invalid SQL.

Comment: they both with symfony looks like sandboxes. be attentive guys

Answer (score 25):

4.6. Quoting Reserved Words

Sometimes it is necessary to quote a column or table name because of reserved word conflicts. **Doctrine does not quote identifiers automatically, because it leads to more problems than it would solve.** Quoting tables and column names needs to be done explicitly using ticks in the definition.

```
<?php
/** @Column(name="`number`", type="integer") */
private $number;
```

Doctrine will then quote this column name in all SQL statements according to the used database platform.

Identifier Quoting does not work for join column names or discriminator column names unless you are using a custom QuoteStrategy.

For more control over column quoting the `Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\QuoteStrategy` interface was introduced in 2.3. It is invoked for every column, table, alias and other SQL names. You can implement the QuoteStrategy and set it by calling `Doctrine\ORM\Configuration#setQuoteStrategy()`.

The ANSI Quote Strategy was added, which assumes quoting is not necessary for any SQL name. You can use it with the following code:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AnsiQuoteStrategy;

$configuration->setQuoteStrategy(new AnsiQuoteStrategy());
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

Answer (score 8):

It's not implemented by Doctrine just because it's too platform-depending.

All you need, is implement own QuoteStrategy.

For example, for symfony project:

---

Copy-paste vendor `AnsiQuoteStrategy` class, rename it and make some quoting:

**AppBundle/ORM/QuoteStrategy.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\ORM;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as M;

class QuoteStrategy implements M\QuoteStrategy
{
  private function quote($token, AbstractPlatform $platform)
  {
    // implement your quote strategy
    switch ($platform->getName()) {
      case 'mysql':
      default:
        return '`' . $token . '`';
    }
  }

  // add quoting to appropriate methods
  public function getColumnName($fieldName, M\ClassMetadata $class, AbstractPlatform $platform)
  {
    return $this->quote($class->fieldMappings[$fieldName]['columnName'], $platform);
  }
  // ... Rest methods
}
```

Then, register your quote strategy as a service:

**src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
  app.orm.quote_strategy:
    class: AppBundle\ORM\QuoteStrategy
    public: false
```

Then, use it for your entitymanager configuration:
**app/config/config.yml**

```
orm:
  entity_managers:
    default:
      quote_strategy: app.orm.quote_strategy
```

That is all :)

Answer (score 3):

Per the statement made by @tim-lytle, I have re-raised the issue.  This really should be included with Doctrine ORM's scope of safety.

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5874