# How to apply Doctrine metadata change in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So I have a MySQL database table called "Release", which unfortunately happens to be a reserved keyword. I ran

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

and now get an SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release t0 WHERE t0.ReleaseID = 2' at line 1

So I manually escaped the table name in class `AppBundle\Entity\Release`.

```
/**
 * Release
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`Release`", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="FK_ProductID_Release", columns={"ProductID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Release
```

I ran

```
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

But am still getting the same error. What else is there to do to notify Doctrine about the change?

Comment: Don't use reserved words for table and columns in Doctrine 2.  D2 does not support auto-escaping for names. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471234/auto-quote-reserved-words-with-doctrine-2

Comment: I know, but unfortunately the database is not in my hand. At least manually escaping should be supported, but I don't get it to work as described in the docs: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

Comment: You can try removing the symfony cache rm -r var/cache or app/cache.  Haves not fooled around with reserved words in awhile.  I suppose you could also try adding your own quoting strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it's quite weird. I followed the guide at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html and 
used the command

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml
```

to generate the description of the existing database. This created files in app/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine which seem to have precedence over the Annotations in the entities. This should be mentioned in the docs.

**Update**
Specifically this part

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
```

in the documentation should be changed to

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src
```

Comment: Somewhere it is mentioned that you can only use one type of mapping per bundle.  It is a very common problem.