# Symfony ManyToOne Relation SQL Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb, symfony-3.3

I am trying to write down transactions in my database. Therefor I have a TransactionEntity, which has the field 'initiator'. This field should be the userId of the user, which is responsible for the transaction. To achive this, I added a ManyToOne relation to the TransactionEntity, but everytime I try to insert a new object, I get SQL errors.

This is my user entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="abistuff_users")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $displayname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json_array")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_visible", type="boolean")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $isVisible;

    //Getters, Setters, and more stuff required for login

}
```

And then I have my transaction entity class:

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $value;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $usage;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $initiator;
```

Here is my function where my form is created and I try to insert my object.

```
public function showAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setMethod("POST")
            ->add('value', NumberType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Wert',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'z.B. "10" oder "-5"', 'autofocus' => ''),
                'scale' => 2
            ))
            ->add('usage', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Verwendungszweck',
                'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Ich musste ganz dringend ganz viele Kekse kaufen...')
            ))
            ->add('date', DateType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Datum',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                'attr' => array('id' => 'form_date')
            ))
            ->add('initiator', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.isVisible = 1')
                        ->orderBy('u.displayname', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'displayname',
                'label' => 'Wer ist dafür verantwortlich?'
            ))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Transaktion hinzufügen',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-success')
            ))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            //Daten aus der Form holen
            $data = $form->getData();

            //Transaction-Objekt bauen
            $transaction = new BankTransaction();
            $transaction->setValue($data['value']);
            $transaction->setUsage($data['usage']);
            $transaction->setDate($data['date']);
            $transaction->setInitiator($data['initiator']);

            //dump($transaction);
            //die();

            //In die DB schreiben
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($transaction);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Neue Transaktion über ' . $transaction->getValue() . ' wurde notiert!');
        }

        return $this->render('/abistuff/user/bank/newtransaction.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

Here is a dump of the object I try to write in the database:

```
BankTransaction {#1145 ▼
  -id: null
  -value: 10.0
  -usage: "Cookies"
  -date: DateTime {#680 ▼
    +"date": "2017-10-23 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  -initiator: User {#805 ▼
    -id: 2
    -username: "user"
    -password: "$2y$13$h7oYgYPS5aN.kJBk7ve8jO.AmQJSKhcvT0qNhPO2Lk6p88c2.j1xG"
    -displayname: "Benutzer"
    -roles: array:1 [▶]
    -isActive: true
    -isVisible: true
  }
}
```

But when I try to persist this object and then try to flush it, it throws this error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException:
>   "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO
>   abistuff_transactions (value, usage, date, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?,
>   ?)' with params [10, "Cookies", "2017-10-23", 2]: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'usage, date, user_id) VALUES
>   (10, 'Cookies', '2017-10-23', 2)' at line 1" at
>   /home/fatih/PhpstormProjects/Abistuff-Symfony4/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   line 90

Can anybody help me?

EDIT: I did not know that "usage" was reserved.

Comment: `usage` is a reserved word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto quote reserved words with Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471234/auto-quote-reserved-words-with-doctrine-2)

Comment: @aynber I am sorry, I did not know, that usage was reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `usage` is a [reserved word](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/) you can't use it. Change the name of the field like :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", name="transaction_usage")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $usage;
```

Or escape it :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", name="`usage`")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $usage;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time!