# How to add quoting for all fields in Doctrine DBAL?

Tags: php, doctrine, dbal

I have some special field names which will work without problems if field names are quoted like this:

```
`field`
```

But my code produces SQL statements without quotes:

```php
$schema = $this->database->getSchemaManager();
$table = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table('teachers');
foreach($header as $field) {
    $table->addColumn($field, "string");
}
$schema->createTable($table);

$this->database->insert('teachers', $data);
// ...
```

How to force DBAL to use quoting for field names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto quote reserved words with Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471234/auto-quote-reserved-words-with-doctrine-2)

Comment: try $table->addColumn('\`' . $field . '\`', "string");

Comment: @svgrafov, I already saw it. But as commented on your awnser it doesn't fix it completely. I'm using only DBAL, not ORM.