# Use reserved keyword as alias in doctrine query builder

Tags: doctrine-orm

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()
->select("MIN(m.price) AS min")
->addSelect('MAX(m.price) AS max')
->from('AppBundle:Sites', 'm');`
```

How can I escape min to make this work? I tried to change `min` Alias to something like `_min` instead but there should be a better way.

I tried both single quotes and backticks but neither worked.

Comment: What is your database management system?

Comment: it's Postgres @goto

Comment: Updated my answer, it seems to be the double quote to escape postgres keyword. Can you confirm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use `min` or `max` as an alias since it is simply not available with the current grammar of the DQL. You can find this info in the [section of the documentation that is defining the grammar of DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf). There you will find out the following:

In [Select Expressions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#select-expressions):

```
SimpleSelectExpression  ::= (...) [["AS"] AliasResultVariable]
```

In [Identifiers](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#identifiers):

```
/* Alias ResultVariable declaration (the "total" of "COUNT(*) AS total") */
AliasResultVariable = identifier
```

And eventually, in [Terminals](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#terminals):

> identifier (name, email, …) must match `[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*`

As you can see, there is nothing in there to help you escape your keyword in anyway. Thus, as it is, when stumbling upon `min`, the Lexer will identify it as the MIN function (see [this section of the code](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Query.Lexer.html#172-191)) and not as an identifier, hence the error.

---

Long story short, you will have to either rely on a native query or use an alias name that is not one of the reserved keywords [listed here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Query.Lexer.html#59-115).

*Note: Doctrine allows you to implement your [own quoting strategy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words) as discussed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471234/auto-quote-reserved-words-with-doctrine-2) but the issue is unrelated. Here, the problem with your alias is that it is matched as a function by the DQL parser which is unexpected at this position.*

Answer (score 1):

Using Mysql, you could escape it using the backtick `` `min` ``
Using Postgres, you could escape it using the doublequote `"min"`

You can use another word like `minimum` as an alias to avoid being database dependant

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work either, I think I will go with `minimum`