# Syntax error or access violation with Symfony and Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I got the error `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Syntax error near 'read = '1' WHERE id = 1' at line 1`

Here is my controller action method :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/show/{id}", name="pm_show", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
     */
    public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->initialize();

        $user = $this->getUser();
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pm::class);
        $messId = $id;
        $messageUser = $repository->findByMessId($messId);

        if ($messageUser[0]['read'] == 0)
        {
            $message = $repository->find($messageUser[0]['id']);
            if (!$message) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                    'No message found for id '.$messageUser[0]['id']
                );
            }
            /**********************************************/
            $message->setRead('1');
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            /**********************************************/
        }

        $this->addToTemplateArray(array (
            'mess_id' => $messId,
            'message' => $messageUser
        ));

        return $this->render('pm/pm_show.html.twig', $this->templateArray);
    }
```

And my entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * App\Entity\Pm
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pm")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PmRepository")
 */
class Pm
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var App\Entity\User $sender
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sender", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $sender;

    /**
     *
     * @var App\Entity\User $recipient
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipient", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $recipient;

    /**
     * @var string $title
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var text $content
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var datetime $time
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="time", type="datetime")
     */
    private $time;

    /**
     * @var string $read
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="read", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $read;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set sender
     *
     * @param integer $sender
     */
    public function setSender($sender)
    {
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }

    /**
     * Get sender
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getSender()
    {
        return $this->sender;
    }

    /**
     * Set recipient
     *
     * @param integer $recipient
     */
    public function setRecipient($recipient)
    {
        $this->recipient = $recipient;
    }

    /**
     * Get recipient
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRecipient()
    {
        return $this->recipient;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param text $content
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return text
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set time
     *
     * @param datetime $time
     */
    public function setTime($time)
    {
        $this->time = $time;
    }

    /**
     * Get time
     *
     * @return datetime 
     */
    public function getTime()
    {
        return $this->time;
    }

    /**
     * Set read
     *
     * @param string $read
     */
    public function setRead($read)
    {
        $this->read = $read;
    }

    /**
     * Get read
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRead()
    {
        return $this->read;
    }
}
```

I don't know why this error is there. I don't see any syntax error and I tried to update the title for example of my Pm entity and it works. Then The problem is only with read column. Maybe there is an access violation but I don't see it.
I tried also to update manually in the database and it works. Thanks for help.

Comment: `read` is mysql reserved word, and doctrine __does not escape them__.

Comment: A topic for you to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471234/auto-quote-reserved-words-with-doctrine-2

Comment: Doctrine doesn't escape column names unless you tell it to, as of version 2 at least. See https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5874

Comment: Interesting, thanks guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto quote reserved words with Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471234/auto-quote-reserved-words-with-doctrine-2)