# Doctrine and quoting reserved word of MySql

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have in my Symfony 4.3 project entity named Group and table group in MySql database. Group is a reserved word. I have 3 entities : User, Group, UserGroup. They have relations:  User ->OneToMany-> UserGroup   and Group -> OneToMany -> UserGroup ( UserGroup has additional attributes, so I can't use ManyToMany relation). When I try to get group names for user with id=1:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $user = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class)
        ->find($id);
   $groups = $user->getUserGroups();

   foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $group_name = $group->getGroupId()->getName();
        echo $group_name, '<br>';
    }
```

I get error message :

You have an error: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS name_2 FROM group t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params [1]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group t0 WHERE t0.id = 1' at line 1 with code: 0

There is a recipe in documentation (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words) how to enable quoting of reserved words:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AnsiQuoteStrategy;

$configuration->setQuoteStrategy(new AnsiQuoteStrategy());
```

I don't understand where I have to use this code - in EntityManager, in Controller? And how I can get $configuration?

Comment: What makes you think that you need to configure anything? Is there anything not working when you skip this part? Then please share the code in question (that one triggering the error) and some version information

Comment: I have Symfony 4.3 and you can see my code in the body of my question.

Comment: Did you try using back-ticks in the table definition?

Comment: Yes, I tried. To no avail. I have solved my problem by implementing my own QuoteStrategy  according https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471234/auto-quote-reserved-words-with-doctrine-2/47036212#47036212

Answer (score 4):

I think the better solution is to use ticks in the definition of your entity as mentioned in [Doctrine Documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words).

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GroupRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`group`")
 */
class Group
{
    // ...
}
```

Note, that this approach will work only if you are using the default quote strategy. So, delete `quote_strategy` parameter or set it as `doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.default`.

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yml

doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        quote_strategy: doctrine.orm.quote_strategy.default
```