# Doctrine getting SQL error on saving model

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine for the first time and it looks pretty cool. But I can't save models to the database.

Currently I'm using PHP 7.4 and Doctrine 2.7.0.

I have simple Model:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="place")
 */
class Place {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected int $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true) */
    private string $name;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private int $ignore = 0;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIgnore(): int {
        return $this->ignore;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $ignore
     */
    public function setIgnore(int $ignore): void {
        $this->ignore = $ignore;
    }
}
```

The table sturcture looks like that:
[image]

Thorugh the tutorial (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/getting-started.html) I learned that I can create a new Object like that:

```
$p = new Place();
$p->setName("hello");
```

And save it to the database like that:

```
$entityManager = Doctrine::setup(); // sets up the entity manager
$entityManager->getConnection()
    ->getConfiguration()
    ->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());
$entityManager->persist($p);
$entityManager->flush();
```

But I get the following SQL Error (including debug information):

```
"START TRANSACTION"
INSERT INTO place (name, ignore) VALUES (?, ?)
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  [2]=>
  int(0)
}
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(6) "string"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "integer"
}
"ROLLBACK"

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ignore) VALUES ('hello', 0)'
```

I thought, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I tried it with other models too, but I always get that error.

Comment: well it's the same as the object

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: What happens when you run this query in DB? `INSERT INTO place (name, ignore) VALUES ("hello", 0)`

Comment: Nice idea, I found the problem. I can't use "ignore" without "`". Is there a way to quote the column names in doctrine?

Comment: No, because `ignore` is MYSQL keyword i.e. a reserved word. Learn more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be worked around using backticks, please have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570215/832691

Comment: Since I noticed, that I can't use ignore as a column, I already found that solution. But I also found a solution with a QuoteStrategy. But I can't get it to work. Do you have any idea how to implement the QuoteStrategy, so I don't need to use backticks?