# Symfony SQL error message : "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064"

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have an error that I don't comprehend :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO achats (year_month,
>   modele, code_reference, date_de_ajout, cout, date_de_achat,
>   importance, ordre, type, location_de_achat) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2020-07", "St\u2011Luc
>   (echo\u2011graphie)", null, "2020-01-23", 2.97, "2020-01-23", null,
>   13, 24, 7]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'year_month,
>   modele, code_reference, date_de_ajout, cout, date_de_achat, importan'
>   at line 1

My Entity is :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Achats
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="achats", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="type", columns={"type", "location_de_achat"}), @ORM\Index(name="location_de_achat", columns={"location_de_achat"}), @ORM\Index(name="Modele", columns={"Modele"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_9920924E8CDE5729", columns={"type"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Achats
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return Achats
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="year_month", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 7,
     *      max = 7,
     *      minMessage = "Your date name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
     *      maxMessage = "Your date name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters"
     * )
     */
    private $yearMonth;

    public function getYearMonth(): ?string
    {
        return $this->yearMonth;
    }

    public function setYearMonth(string $yearMonth): self
    {
        $this->yearMonth = $yearMonth;

        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="modele", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $modele;

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getModele()
    {
        return $this->modele;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $modele
     * @return Achats
     */
    public function setModele($modele)
    {
        $this->modele = $modele;
        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code_reference", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $codeReference;

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCodeReference()
    {
        return $this->codeReference;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $codeReference
     * @return Achats
     */
    public function setCodeReference($codeReference)
    {
        $this->codeReference = $codeReference;
        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_de_ajout", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateDeAjout;

    /**
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
    public function getDateDeAjout()
    {
        return $this->dateDeAjout;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime|null $dateDeAjout
     * @return Achats
     */
    public function setDateDeAjout($dateDeAjout)
    {
        $this->dateDeAjout = $dateDeAjout;
        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cout", type="float", nullable=true, options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $cout;

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getCout()
    {
        return $this->cout;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|null $cout
     * @return Achats
     */
    public function setCout($cout)
    {
        $this->cout = $cout;
        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_de_achat", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateDeAchat;

    /**
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
    public function getDateDeAchat()
    {
        return $this->dateDeAchat;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime|null $dateDeAchat
     * @return Achats
     */
    public function setDateDeAchat($dateDeAchat)
    {
        $this->dateDeAchat = $dateDeAchat;
        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @var \Types
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Types")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @return \Types
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Types $type
     * @return Achats
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @var \Lieux
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lieux")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_de_achat", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $locationDeAchat;

    /**
     * @return \Lieux
     */
    public function getLocationDeAchat()
    {
        return $this->locationDeAchat;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Lieux $locationDeAchat
     * @return Achats
     */
    public function setLocationDeAchat($locationDeAchat)
    {
        $this->locationDeAchat = $locationDeAchat;
        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $importance;

    public function getImportance(): ?int
    {
        return $this->importance;
    }

    public function setImportance(?int $importance): self
    {
        $this->importance = $importance;

        return $this;
    }

    //=======================================================================================

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $ordre;

    public function getOrdre(): ?int
    {
        return $this->ordre;
    }

    public function setOrdre(?int $ordre): self
    {
        $this->ordre = $ordre;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Achats;
use App\Form\AchatsType;
use App\Form\AchatsNewType;
use Exception;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
class AchatsController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="achats_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $achats = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Achats::class)
            ->findAll();

        return $this->render('achats/index.html.twig', [
            'achats' => $achats,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/achats/new", name="achats_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $achat = new Achats();
        $form = $this->createForm(AchatsNewType::class, $achat);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $now = new \DateTime('now');

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($achat);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('achats_index');
        }

        return $this->render('achats/new.html.twig', [
            'achat' => $achat,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/achats/{id}", name="achats_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(Achats $achat): Response
    {
        return $this->render('achats/show.html.twig', [
            'achat' => $achat,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/achats/{id}/edit", name="achats_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Achats $achat): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(AchatsType::class, $achat);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('achats_index');
        }

        return $this->render('achats/edit.html.twig', [
            'achat' => $achat,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/achats/{id}", name="achats_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, Achats $achat): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$achat->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($achat);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('achats_index');
    }
}
```

Form :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Achats;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class AchatsNewType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('importance', IntegerType::class, [

                'required' => false,

                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Importance',
                    'min' => '0',
                    'max' => '100',
                    'step' => '0.01'
                ]
            ])

            ->add('yearMonth', TextType::class, [

                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'YYYY‑MM',
                    'min' => '7',
                    'max' => '7',
                ]
            ])

            ->add('ordre', IntegerType::class, [

                'required' => false,

                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Ordre d\'importance',
                    'min' => '1',
                    'step' => '1'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('modele', TextType::class, [])

            ->add('codeReference', TextType::class, [

                'required' => false,
            ])

            ->add('dateDeAjout', DateType::class, [

                'data' => new \DateTime(),
            ])

            ->add('cout', NumberType::class, [

                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Coût',
                    'min' => '0',
                    'step' => '0.01'
                ]
            ])

            ->add('dateDeAchat', DateType::class, [

                'data' => new \DateTime(),
            ])

            ->add('type')

            ->add('locationDeAchat');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Achats::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Please, if someone have an advice, I will be grateful.

Comment: If there is no any invisible (non-printable) byte or char between opening bracket and  `year_month` than the only visible reason may be that `year_month` is treated as an interval measurement unit...

Answer (score 6):

> year_month

is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) so it can't be used as column name without special treatment

You need to enclose it in backticks in your query, like so

```
`year_month`
```

So your query would be

```sql
'INSERT INTO achats (`year_month`, modele, code_reference ...
```

As you're using Symfony I'll assume you're using Doctrine as well, in which case you need to [tell the ORM to use the backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570215/1081756) in its generated queries

Comment: For reference, see [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-Y) and [Temporal Interval Arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-interval-arguments).