# Why does symfony creates incorrect mysql request

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, pdo

my entities, looks like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ExperienceRepository::class)
 */
class Experience
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\Range(
     *     min=0,
     *     max=100
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"experience:read", "experience:write"})
     */
    private $years;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Limit::class, mappedBy="experience")
     * @Groups({"experience:read"})
     */
    private $limits;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=LimitRepository::class)
 */
class Limit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"limit:read"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"limit:read", "limit:write"})
     */
    private $limitDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Groups({"limit:read", "limit:write"})
     */
    private $limitValue;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Experience::class, inversedBy="limits")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $experience;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"limit:read"})
     */
    private $createdAt = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"limit:read"})
     */
    private $updatedAt = null;
```

When im trying to create objects, and save it in database, i do next steps(in controller):

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $exp = new Experience();
        $exp->setYears(5);
        $em->persist($exp);
        $em->flush();

        $l = new Limit();
        $l->setLimitValue((1 + 2 + 1) * 1000);
        $l->setLimitDate(new \DateTime());
        $l->setExperience($exp);

        $em->persist($l);
        $em->flush();
```

So after that, i got error:

> An exception occurred while executing '`INSERT INTO limit (limit_date, limit_value, created_at, updated_at, experience_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`' with params `["2020-06-03 11:01:56", 4000, null, null, 51]`:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`limit (limit_date, limit_value, created_at, updated_at, experience_id) VALUES ('`' at line 1

What am i do wrong ?

Comment: Your ORM is failing to escape identifiers that need so (`limit` in this case). It should be automatic but I'm not familiar with Symfony.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you very much ! its true!)

Comment: maybe it is expecting a float and not an integer.

/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Groups({"limit:read", "limit:write"})
     */
    private $limitValue;

Comment: Limit is a keyword in mysql so the easiest solution is to rename your entity class which will automatically rename your db table. Something else you can try is to add `@ORM\Table(name="exp_limit")` to your entity class annotation.

Comment: Does Symfony use [Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47036212/13508)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes !)

Comment: Have you tried to add `@Table("""limit""")` to force escaping of “limit” keyword?