# Doctrine entity with a space in its table name, problem with detecting differences in Symfony application

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need a space in table name. I've found that the following works (note the *spacing*):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(" `dettagli cantieri2` ")
 */
class CommissionLine
{
}
```

However after updating the schema, difference are not detected. That means that after running `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` the same table would be re-created, like it was not detected.

I'm running:

```
doctrine/annotations                v1.6.0 Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                      v1.7.1 Caching library offering an object-oriented API for m...
doctrine/collections                v1.5.0 Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                     v2.8.1 Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                       v2.7.2 Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle            1.8.1  Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle      1.3.2  Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle v1.3.2 Symfony DoctrineMigrationsBundle
doctrine/inflector                  v1.3.0 Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and...
doctrine/instantiator               1.1.0  A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects i...
doctrine/lexer                      v1.0.1 Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down...
doctrine/migrations                 v1.8.1 Database Schema migrations using Doctrine DBAL
doctrine/orm                        v2.6.6 Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
```

Along with Symfony:

```
symfony/assetic-bundle     v2.8.2 Integrates Assetic into Symfony2
symfony/monolog-bundle     v3.1.2 Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge     v3.4.4 Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-apcu      v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP ver...
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu  v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-related data and classes
symfony/polyfill-mbstring  v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php56     v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower P...
symfony/polyfill-php70     v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower P...
symfony/polyfill-util      v1.7.0 Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/security-acl       v3.0.1 Symfony Security Component - ACL (Access Control List)
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle v2.6.7 Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony            v3.4.4 The Symfony PHP framework
```

Comment: What database are you using? Postgres? MySQL?

Comment: Why a space between `"` and `\``?

Comment: Doctrine and backticks don't get along very well.  [Here is a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471234/auto-quote-reserved-words-with-doctrine-2).  Not really surprised you have run into problems.